# List joint table records

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a set of tables as following:

customer(**cus_id**,cus_name)

account(**acc_num**,acc_balance,**bra_code**)

branch(**bra_code**,bra_address)

if i want to list all customer who have accounts in more than one, branch and their details.
Im new to oracle hope everyone can help.

It's part of my assignment actually, so far what I did is like this..

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        C.CUS_ID, 
        (C.CUS_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || C.CUS_LAST_NAME) AS CUS_NAME,
        C.CUS_IC, 
        C.CUS_ADDRESS, 
        C.CUS_POSTCODE, 
        C.CUS_CONTACT, 
        C.CUS_EMAIL, 
        C.CUS_AGE,     
        C.CUS_GENDER, 
        C.CUS_STATUS,
        B.BRA_CODE, 
        B.BRA_ADDRESS, 
        B.BRA_POSTCODE, 
        R.REG_STATE, 
        R.REG_COUNTRY
FROM CUSTOMER C, ACCOUNT A,BRANCH B, REGION R
WHERE C.CUS_ID=A.CUS_ID AND 
      A.BRA_CODE=B.BRA_CODE AND 
      B.REG_ID=R.REG_ID AND 
      A.BRA_CODE IN (SELECT A.BRA_CODE
                     FROM CUSTOMER C, ACCOUNT A,BRANCH B
                     WHERE C.CUS_ID=A.CUS_ID AND A.BRA_CODE=B.BRA_CODE
                     GROUP BY A.BRA_CODE HAVING COUNT(A.BRA_CODE)>1)
GROUP BY 
        C.CUS_ID,
        C.CUS_FIRST_NAME,
        C.CUS_LAST_NAME,
        C.CUS_IC, 
        C.CUS_ADDRESS, 
        C.CUS_POSTCODE, 
        C.CUS_CONTACT, 
        C.CUS_EMAIL, 
        C.CUS_AGE, 
        C.CUS_GENDER, 
        C.CUS_STATUS, 
        B.BRA_CODE, 
        B.BRA_ADDRESS, 
        B.BRA_POSTCODE, 
        R.REG_STATE, 
        R.REG_COUNTRY 
        HAVING COUNT(C.CUS_ID)>1;
```

Comment: Show us what your query looks like so far

Comment: Hi, i updated my question, please help :)

Comment: +1 for including table structures and for the fact that this is for Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c, account a, branch b
WHERE c.cus_id IN (
        SELECT a2.cus_id
        FROM account a2, branch b2
        WHERE a2.bra_code = b2.bra_code
        GROUP BY a2.cus_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(b2.bra_code)) > 1
    )
    AND c.cus_id = a.cus_id
    AND a.bra_code = b.bra_code
```

Comment: This assumes that there will never be more than one account per customer in any one branch.

Answer (score 2):

One answer might be something like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        C.CUS_ID, 
        (C.CUS_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || C.CUS_LAST_NAME) AS CUS_NAME,
        C.CUS_IC, 
        C.CUS_ADDRESS, 
        C.CUS_POSTCODE, 
        C.CUS_CONTACT, 
        C.CUS_EMAIL, 
        C.CUS_AGE,     
        C.CUS_GENDER, 
        C.CUS_STATUS,
        B.BRA_CODE, 
        B.BRA_ADDRESS, 
        B.BRA_POSTCODE, 
        R.REG_STATE, 
        R.REG_COUNTRY
FROM CUSTOMER C, ACCOUNT A,BRANCH B, REGION R
WHERE C.CUS_ID=A.CUS_ID AND 
      A.BRA_CODE=B.BRA_CODE AND 
      B.REG_ID=R.REG_ID AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ACCOUNT O
              WHERE A.CUS_ID = O.CUS_ID AND A.BRA_CODE <> O.BRA_CODE)
```